# simple getElementsByClassName javascript not working in wordpress footer

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a 1 liner JS in the footer and I can't get getElementsByClassName to work to tweak style attributes.  "Hello World" works, so it must be my syntax?

The footer code is this:

```
<script>
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-widget-container");
test.style.background-color = 'white';  
var widgets = document.getElementsByClassName("widgets_wrapper");
widgets.style.margin = "0px";
</script>
```

Comment: `test.style.background-color` should be `test[0].style.backgroundColor`

Comment: Should be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return [messed up my close vote]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return  this worked ty.  getElementByID is easier.  Too many same name classes on my site.  None of the get classes functions worked.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes.
Even if there's only one.

So what you (probably) want to do is:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName[0]
```

In the future, try, for instance,
to run console.log(test) to see what you're working with, before writing more code to manipulate that variable/element.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array like object, even if theres only one. You can try:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-widget-container")[0];
```

or:

```
test[0].style.background-color = 'white';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that test is an array of Node not only Node. So, you will do like this :

```
<script>
    let tests = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-widget-container");
    tests.forEach( test => { test.style.background-color = 'white'; } );  
    let widgets = document.getElementsByClassName("widgets_wrapper");
    widgets.forEach( widget => { widget.style.margin = "0px"; } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally got it to work, but had to change strategy:

> document.getElementById("menu-item-205").style.backgroundColor =
> "red";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).